# Why does Google map work on one of my devices, but shows up blank on all other devices, yet the GPS coords still work?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an app that uses Google Play Services to show a map and get coordinates (Lat/Long) either automatically, or by letting the user manually select a specific spot on the map and long press to get that specific coordinate. I got an API key and put it in my Manifest, everything I am supposed to do. The app works perfectly on my personal phone, shows map with current position and everything, but on a different device, used for testing, with the same android OS (4.2) the map area is blank, yet I can push the "Get GPS" button and still get my current Lat/Long. It just keeps me from being able to manually select location. I was wondering if there is some API key I have to have to allow proper functionality on multiple devices and maybe I just got one that will work on one device, or if it's because that one device is using my Google account? When I make changes to the app, and reinstall on my personal phone, it still works, but again, same prob on other devices.

Comment: The API key is linked only to an app id, not to any device. Please ensure that the other devices have Google Play Services installed. GPS reading is not linked to google maps

Comment: Google Play Services is installed and updated on other devices. I will try to run another app that also uses maps and see if it works there.

Comment: Maps works fine on other devices, just not the map in this particular app, but it does still work on my personal device.

Comment: Also, API Key is correct. Again, works on one device, but just blank screen on others.

Comment: Are there any logcat outupt relatet with gmaps? And, did you test you to configure your app and the api console using the release key?

Comment: Did you generate your API key using the SHA1 from the debug keystore?  How are you installing the app on all devices (the same method you used on the working device) and are you the one installing the app to the other devices or is it other users/developers?